# Can I avoid using Option A when I know that head cannot fail?

Tags: coq, convoy-pattern

I am quite new in the world of the ATP, but definitely very motivated.
I am starting to deal with dependent types. I am involved in a project where I have defined the type for (finite and infinite) sequences.

```
Inductive sequence {X : Type} : Type :=
    | FinSeq (x : list X)
    | InfSeq (f : nat -> X).
```

Now I want to define the head of a non-empty sequence.

```
Lemma aux_hd : forall {A : Type} (l : list A),
    0 < Datatypes.length l  -> @hd_error A l = None -> False.
Proof. destruct l.
 + simpl. lia. 
 + simpl. intros S. discriminate.
Qed.

Definition Hd {A : Type} (l : list A) : 0 < Datatypes.length l -> A :=
    match (hd_error l) with
    | Some a => (fun _ => a)
    | None => fun pf => match (aux_hd l pf ??) with end
    end.
     
Definition Head {A : Type} (s :sequence) (H : 0 << length s),
     match s with 
     | FinSeq x => Hd x H 
     | InfSeq f => f 0 end.
```

My problem is in the definition of Hd: I don't know how to prove `@hd_error A l = None`, since we are already in such a match branch. I believe it should be really easy.

I have a similar problem in the last definition because I don't know how to transform H, for the particular case of the first match branch, where I know that `length s = Datatypes.length x` and, thus, `0 << length s -> 0 < Datatypes.length x`.

Finally, I have omitted the details about << and length sequence, because I dont think it is relevant for the question but basically I have uplifted nat with an Inf to represent the length of the infinite sequences and << is the < for nat and num.

I have followed the course Software Foundations and I am currently studying more using "Certified Programming with Dependent Types" which is also really good.
Thanks in advance,
Miguel

Answer (score 2):

When you `match` on something, all extra evidence must be passed as arguments to the match (this is the "convoy pattern" described in CPDT).

In `Hd` you want to remember that `hd_error l = None`, pass it as an argument. It's a little tricky because you have to explicitly annotate the `match` with a `return` clause (which in simpler cases was inferred for you):

```
Definition Hd {A : Type} (l : list A) : 0 < Datatypes.length l -> A :=
    match (hd_error l) as X return hd_error l = X -> 0 < Datatypes.length l -> A with
    | Some a => (fun _ _ => a)
    | None => fun pf1 pf2 => match (aux_hd l pf2 pf1) with end
    end eq_refl.
```

Similarly in `Head`, after pattern-matching on `s` you want to simplify `0 << length s`; pass it as an argument:

```
Definition Head {A : Type} (s :sequence) (H : 0 << length s) :=
     match s return (0 << length s) -> _ with 
     | FinSeq x => fun H => Hd x H 
     | InfSeq f => fun _ => f 0
     end H.
```